# Adding view on play button clicked

Tags: javascript, php

Currently I have the following block of code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#player2").flatie({
    media: {
    mp3: "http://example.com/uploads/tracks/181013770_166109597_2017017040.mp3"
}
    }).jPlayer("play");
});
```

I am trying to make it so that when a user presses the play button on my player it sets off a command which generates a view.

**adview.php** is the name of the file, I am unsure how to do this however using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, after user clicks on some button, you want to load already created view? If that's the case, try this:

```
$('#buttonThatNeedsToBePressed').click(function(){
    $('#elementInWitchYouWantViewToBeLoaded').load('path/to/adview.php');     
});
```

Of course, adjust these selectors to elements of your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind to the `play` event of jPlayer, than add the code that Ognj3n mentioned.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#player2").flatie({
        media: {
        mp3: "http://example.com/uploads/tracks/181013770_166109597_2017017040.mp3"
    }
        }).jPlayer("play");
    });
    $("#player2").bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function(event) {
        $('#elementInWhichYouWantViewToBeLoaded').load('path/to/adview.php');
    });
</script>
```

If you need to unbind the play event, can do so also:

`$("#player2").unbind($.jPlayer.event.play);`